# A $5\times 5$ Matrix with No Eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields

It can be observed that a matrix of order $5$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has at least one eigenvalue in $\mathbb{R}$.

What if we consider a finite field?

For example, over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, a matrix having characteristic polynomial $x^4(x-1)+1$ cannot have an eigenvalue from $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Can such a matrix exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given any polynomial $f$ over a field $F$, you can always construct a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) over $F$ whose characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial are both equal to $f$.  (Other properties of $f$, such as whether $f$ has a zero over $F$, or whether $f$ is irreducible over $F$, are irrelevant.) In your case, $x^4(x-1)+1=x^5-x^4+1$ is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix
$$
C=\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&-1\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you @user1551